# Установка node js и npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Установил node.js, проверяю в консоли версию

[image]

А вот проверка npm вызывают гору ошибок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что, собственно, не так?

Comment: День добрый. У нас ошибки принято вставлять текстом.

Comment: уверен, что ему не нравится слово `ПХП` в пути, желательно чтобы не было латиницы в названиях дерикторий

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Создайте переменную среды `APPDATA` со значением `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\npm;npm`.